# Is my approach to the following Probability theory question valid?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

This problem shows one way to generate discrete random variables from a uniform random number generator. Suppose that F is the cdf of an integer-valued random variable; Let U be uniform on $[0,1]$. Define a random variable $Y = k$ if $F(k-1)< U \leq F(k)$. Show that $Y$ has cdf F.

(Taken from Mathematical Statistics and Data Analysis 3rd Edition, Chapter 2 - problem 71)

Solution:

I utilized the following propositions from the text and would like to know if my application is valid. If not, why is that the case.

**Proposition C**:

Let $Z = F(X)$; then $Z$ has a uniform distribution on $[0,1]$.

**Proposition D**:

Let $U$ be uniform on $[0,1]$, and let $X = F^{-1}(U)$. Then the cdf of $X$ is $F$.

Now, since $F(k-1)< U \leq F(k)$ then

$F^{-1}(F(k-1))< F^{-1}(U) \leq F^{-1}(F(k))$

$k-1< F^{-1}(U) \leq k$

I noted that $Y = k = F^{-1}(F(k))$ and where let $Z = F(k)$ and use **proposition C** to determine that $Z$ has a uniform distribution. That would give us $Y = F^{-1}(Z)$ and by **proposition D** we conclude that the cdf of $Y$ is $F$.

Comment: I think your "proposition C" is mis-stated.  If $X$ is an integer random variable and  $F$ is its cdf, then $Z=F(X)$ is certainly not uniformly distributed.

Comment: Well the text didn't mention whether $X$ was continuous or discrete. Only that it was a random variable.

Comment: I do believe you're correct though but here's the paragraph before these were stated:




"We conclude this section by developing some results relating the uniform distribution to other continuous distributions. Throughout, we consider a random variable $X$, with density $f$ and cdf $F$, where $F$ is strictly increasing on some interval $I$, $F = 0$ to the left of $I$, and $F = 1$ to the right of $I$. $I$ may be a bounded interval or an unbounded interval such as the whole real line. $F^{-1}(x)$ is then well defined on $I$"

Comment: If $X$ has a density, it is a continuous rv.  Integer valued rvs are not continuous.  Your application of Proposition C is flawed, as your $X$ is not continuous.

Comment: I see, thank you I understand.